# Executing Jquery In mobile MVC Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using the jquery mobile template from visual studio. In my Layout view I have the following markup

```
   <div data-role="page"  @(Page.Id == null ? string.Empty : "id=" + Page.Id) data-fullscreen="false">
```

When my Browse view is rendered I want to change the data-fullscreen attibute to true. Here is the code I am attempting to use to do this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#indexPage").live('pageinit', function () {
            alert("Code Engaged");
            $("#div").attr("data-fullscreen", "true");
        });
</script>
```

I cannot get this code to engage. Where do I place the code to engage it? The layout has several sections..

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
       Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>@Page.Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="jQuery Mobile Site">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!--  Mobile viewport optimized: j.mp/bplateviewport -->
  @*<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">*@
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


  <!-- jQuery Mobile Latest Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />

  @* // reference the minified version of our combined css based on whether we are in debug mode. *@
  @if (jQueryMobileTemplate.MvcApplication.IsDebug)
  { 
   @* <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.css?v=2")" />*@
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/custom%20themes/electric1.css?v=2")" /> 

  }
  else
  {
   @* <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.min.css?v=2")" />*@
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/custom%20themes/electric1.min.css?v=2")" />


  }

  <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
  <!-- We put these at the top because jquery mobile applies styles before the page finishes loading -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">


  </script>
  <script>      window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='@Url.Content("~/js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")'>\x3C/script>")</script>

  <!-- Pre jQuery Mobile init scripts for overriding defaults -->
  <script>

  </script>

  <!-- Load jQuery Mobile from jquery cdn, get latest builds -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js">

  </script>
  @* <!-- Optionally, load from local site -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js")"></script>
  *@

  @RenderSection("HeadContent", false)

  @*<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/libs/respond.min.js")"></script>*@


</head>
```

I tried it at the bottom of my "Browse" view as well but nothing. I just want the "Browse" view to execute this code.

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="indexPage"` in your DOM? I see that you are assigning `string.Empty` in case Page.Id is null. `$("#indexPage")` won't do much if you don't have such element.

Comment: I am using the mvc jqm mobile template. You are right there is an empty string as the page id. The page id is set to string.empty in the layout view. How do I set the id for the browse view to "indexPage" Page is a WebBasePage dynamic variable. How can I set this to "indexPage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageinit` event has never properly worked for me either for some reason when I'm using asp.net-mvc. You can try using one of the [page change events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) (`pagebeforechange` or `pagechange`) instead.